# Extend Java Rest interface with OAUTH 2.0

Tags: java, rest, oauth-2.0, jersey

I need to add OAUTH 2.0 to my current interface. Which library would be most suitable for this?
I wouldn't like to completely adjust everything again.

Is there a way to integrate OAUTH 2.0 into the current structure?

This is my Send class, it receives a request with all the necessary information.

```
package com.prologistik.sst.ws.fts.outgoing.http;

import javax.ws.rs.HttpMethod;
import javax.ws.rs.client.Client;
import javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder;
import javax.ws.rs.client.Entity;
import javax.ws.rs.client.Invocation;
import javax.ws.rs.client.WebTarget;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientConfig;
import org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientProperties;
import org.glassfish.jersey.client.HttpUrlConnectorProvider;

import com.prologistik.sst.ws.fts.data.Request;
import com.prologistik.sst.ws.fts.interfaces.HTTPClient;
import com.prologistik.sst.ws.fts.interfaces.IncResponseHandler;
import com.prologistik.utils.PLKonstanten;

public class FTSHTTPClient implements HTTPClient {

    private final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass());
    private final int timeout_write;
    private final int timeout_read;
    private final IncResponseHandler responseHandler;

    public FTSHTTPClient(int timeout_write, int timeout_read, IncResponseHandler rhandler) {
        this.timeout_write = timeout_write;
        this.timeout_read = timeout_read;
        this.responseHandler = rhandler;
    }

    @Override
    public void send(Request req) {
        logger.info("START path/id <" + req.getUrl() + ">");

        try {
            ClientConfig configuration = new ClientConfig();
            configuration.property(ClientProperties.CONNECT_TIMEOUT, timeout_write);
            configuration.property(ClientProperties.READ_TIMEOUT, timeout_read);
            Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient(configuration);
            
            WebTarget webTarget = client.target(req.getUrl());
            webTarget.property(HttpUrlConnectorProvider.SET_METHOD_WORKAROUND, true);

            int status;
            String output;
            Invocation.Builder request = webTarget.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                    .accept(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_TYPE);
            Response res;
            System.out.println(req.getUrl() + "\n" + req.getRequestData());
            switch (req.getMethod()) {
            case POST:
                res = request.post(Entity.json(req.getRequestData()));
                break;
            case PUT:
                res = request.put(Entity.json(req.getRequestData()));
                break;
            case PATCH:
                res = request.method(HttpMethod.PATCH, Entity.json(req.getRequestData()));
                break;
            case DELETE:
                res = request.delete();
                break;
            default:
                throw new IllegalStateException("Request Method " + req.getMethod() + " nicht unterstuetzt");
            }
            try (Response s = res) {
                status = s.getStatus();
                output = s.readEntity(String.class);
                System.out.println(output);
            }
            if (status >= 400) {
                responseHandler.handleError(req, output);
            } else {
                responseHandler.handleOkay(req, output);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.warn("Fehler " + e.getMessage(), e);
            req.getMonitors().notify(PLKonstanten.Z_FEHLER, e.getLocalizedMessage(), null);
        }
        logger.info("ENDE");
    }
}
```

I have already looked at a few libraries, but a complete replacement of the logic would always be necessary. I would like to save this effort.